# HTML Large Table scrolling very slowly

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a table with thousands upon thousands of rows with 4 cells in each.
https://streamable.com/pywk9

You can see above my table is very big (no idea if its showing very well the laggy scrolling).

I understand this is because the browser has to actually render everything and with large datasets it could take time.

Is there a way WITHOUT pagination to make it more bearable?
Perhaps some way to render content ONLY shown in browsers view like a certain angularJS component (without needing angularjs)

Comment: There's a weight to your payload you have to deal with in a clever manner. First thing (not clear from your question) is whether you load dynamically your data. The logic usually goes: if your server can provide *parts* - than provide parts. one viewport of data + 2 viewports extra. Account for a loading gif aswell :P. Once loaded, don't remove old items (to keep the element to-top-scrollable). If the number of items is greater than 10.000 (5000 on mobile) than you should really think of using a sort-of pagination, or smartly hack the parent scrollbar to keep a pleasant UX.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan So the data is loaded dynamically with HTML DOM (Im using CEFSharp) so I basically handle all the data in C# and then send them off to the HTML DOM. The table is only viewed on a Desktop PC not on Phones ever so thats not a worry. Thing is for the use case I showed in the video, pagination would be fine I guess. But my worry is, how would I paginate when I load stuff in dynamically with tableElem.appendChild?

Comment: If you decide to implement a way to *Partially load data*, than when the user hits a scroll end - simply show a loading bar and load your new set of elements. prepend or append accordingly. Using JS you can calculate the current scroll position, populate the element parent, and trick the scroll back to where it was **visually** before the items loaded. That way the user will get less distracted by the loading process and the new change.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Right but how would I paginate, thats a way to load data in as they scroll, but not a way to paginate :/ I basically want a way to make it so If I have lets say 8 rows, make it be on page 1 and show all 8, if I load in 2 more, show those 2 more, still page 1. If I load another 2, make those in page 2, create a page 2 button and dont show them until I go to page 2, when I click page 2, hide page 1's row. Would display:none be efficient here or do I REALLY have to destroy the elements?

Comment: When using pagination you have two variants: to pull the data from an already preloaded Array of objects - (which could be hard to preload in the first place since we're clearly talking about MBs of data; and for keeping it in RAM - if we're talking of tens of thousands) or to AJAX every set of data on page(ination) click. When using AJAX you could use a method for querying your database which will return N rows from a specific index. If you have 100 items-per-page, and you click `2` you'll load from DB items from index 99 to 199

Comment: Pagination often proves expensive for the first N items - since queried the most (take for example: every user will always want to see the first items by default) but that's OK - Now, take the user knows the items are in alphabetical order (or similar) - You'll get less queries if the user knows he should look at the end or middle of your pagination - which will cost you at least 400 loaded items, rather than (i.e) 20000 for every user - if you preloaded the entire DB array.

Answer (score 0):

A table that size is useful to nobody, you say you don't want to paginate but why? Pagination is a usability feature for a reason. Just implement pagination and searching. A grid with more than a few thousand rows is not going to be useful to anyone.

If you really need to have the table that big and scrollable then the technique used is to remove the item that are not in view out of the DOM. As you scroll you create DOM objects for the items as they come into view and remove them as they move out of view. This way there are not thousands of DOM objects the browser has to deal with.

Comment: If I were to just delete/recreate when in-out view, how would I even scroll in the first place? If im thinking correctly, wouldnt it just fix the overflow once deleting rows? Would visibility:hidden do the same performance effect or would it be noticably worse? id also prefer NOT to have to delete anything at all

Comment: By *plain following* your suggestion one would hit the biggest issue - of hackyjumpy scrollbars due the depletion/addendum of DOM items. And the list goes. Not unsolvable, but clearly not well depicted.